# Something wrong happens when shuffle a tensor

Tags: python, random, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to shuffle a tensor, but I find there is something wrong when tryting to using `random.shuffle()`,here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':

    label_0, label_1 = np.zeros([1, 1000])[0], np.ones([1, 1000])[0]
    test_label = np.hstack((label_0, label_1))

    num_0, num_1 = 0, 0

    for i in range(len(test_label)):
        if test_label[i] == 0:
            num_0 += 1
        elif test_label[i] == 1:
            num_1 += 1

    print('Num1:  ', num_1)
    print('Num0:  ', num_0)

    random.shuffle(test_label)

    num_0, num_1 = 0, 0
    for i in range(len(test_label)):
        if test_label[i] == 0:
            num_0 += 1
        elif test_label[i] == 1:
            num_1 += 1

    print('After Shuffle Num1:  ', num_1)
    print('After Shuffle Num0:  ', num_0)
```

If `test_label` is not a tensor, it works perfectly:

```
Num1:   1000
Num0:   1000
After Shuffle Num1:   1000
After Shuffle Num0:   1000
```

However when I try to transform the `test_label` from `ndarray` to `tensor`, something wrong would happend:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':

    label_0, label_1 = np.zeros([1, 1000])[0], np.ones([1, 1000])[0]
    test_label = np.hstack((label_0, label_1))

    # now transform to tensor
    test_label = torch.tensor(test_label)


    num_0, num_1 = 0, 0

    for i in range(len(test_label)):
        if test_label[i] == 0:
            num_0 += 1
        elif test_label[i] == 1:
            num_1 += 1

    print('Num1:  ', num_1)
    print('Num0:  ', num_0)

    random.shuffle(test_label)

    num_0, num_1 = 0, 0
    for i in range(len(test_label)):
        if test_label[i] == 0:
            num_0 += 1
        elif test_label[i] == 1:
            num_1 += 1

    print('After Shuffle Num1:  ', num_1)
    print('After Shuffle Num0:  ', num_0)
```

And the result seems to be kind wrong:

```
Num1:   1000
Num0:   1000
After Shuffle Num1:   306
After Shuffle Num0:   1694
```

Anybody can tell me why will make such problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `torch.randperm`:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':

    label_0, label_1 = np.zeros([1, 1000])[0], np.ones([1, 1000])[0]
    test_label = np.hstack((label_0, label_1))

    # now transform to tensor
    test_label = torch.tensor(test_label)


    num_0, num_1 = 0, 0

    for i in range(len(test_label)):
        if test_label[i] == 0:
            num_0 += 1
        elif test_label[i] == 1:
            num_1 += 1

    print('Num1:  ', num_1)
    print('Num0:  ', num_0)

    p = torch.randperm(test_label.shape[0])
    test_label = test_label[p]

    num_0, num_1 = 0, 0
    for i in range(len(test_label)):
        if test_label[i] == 0:
            num_0 += 1
        elif test_label[i] == 1:
            num_1 += 1

    print('After Shuffle Num1:  ', num_1)
    print('After Shuffle Num0:  ', num_0)
```